# Building simple 2d javascript game, how to stop game piece leaving the canvass

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-physics

So i'm new to this and have probably coded it wrong to start off with. I'm thinking after doing research that i should have stored my other game pieces in an array or as seperate variables. Please correct me if im wrong.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:5px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacle

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "black", 350, 445);
    blueGamePiece = new component(20, 20, "blue", 20, 20);
    whiteGamePiece = new component(5, 40, "white",400, 20);
    brownGamePiece = new component(25, 25, "brown", 650, 20);
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 700;
        this.canvas.height = 480;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.key = false;
            })
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function(){
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
    if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37) {myGamePiece.speedX = -5; }
    if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39) {myGamePiece.speedX = 5;}
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
    myGamePiece.update();
    blueGamePiece.y += 1;
    blueGamePiece.update();
    whiteGamePiece.y +=3;
    whiteGamePiece.update();
    brownGamePiece.y +=2;
    brownGamePiece.update();
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I simply want to stop myGamePiece leaving the canvass not bounce it back.
Any other advice would be more than welcome.

Thankyou very much in advance.

Comment: i think, what you need to learn is how to use [control statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) 

Then you can use something like this in the newPos function
`if(this.x+this.speedX <0)
 this.x=0;
else if(this.x+this.speedX > 700)
 this.x = 700'
This example uses hard coded numbers. This is in the long run always bad, so use const for this and put it on a better place.
Also, using the same component function for all objects makes it very hard to adjust simple functionality. Maybe you should separate the logic a littlte bit more

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Replace "this.update" function with this code.

```
this.update = function(){
    if(this.x < 0){this.x = 0}
    if(this.y < 0){this.y = 0}
    if(this.x + this.width > myGameArea.canvas.width){this.x = myGameArea.canvas.width - this.width}
    if(this.y + this.height > myGameArea.canvas.height){this.y = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height}
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```